# gulp-minify not working with gulp-rename

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-rename

code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var minify = require('gulp-minify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('compress', function() {
  gulp.src('script-source.js')
    .pipe(minify())
    .pipe(rename('script1.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

in same folder it is creating a new file script1.js but its not compressed, its same copy..

Answer (score 0):

Using gulp-rename could be the choice https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename 
For more detail https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/34

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add return statement in your gulp task.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show an example of what it should look like?